# How to parse Complex response with use of ksoap2 library in android

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Hi all i am parsing following type of response with use of Ksoap2 library but not getting success to get result my request is like this:

```
                         <soapenv:Header/>
                           <soapenv:Body>
                              <tem:Register>  
                                 <tem:user>         
                                    <jir:Area>testArea</jir:Area>  
                                    <jir:AvailableBalance>0</jir:AvailableBalance>
                                    <jir:CityId>1</jir:CityId>
                                    <jir:Email>test@test.com</jir:Email>
                                    <jir:FullName></jir:FullName>
                                    <jir:Gender>M</jir:Gender>
                                    <jir:Mobile>111111111</jir:Mobile>
                                    <jir:Password>acxcsgsdvs</jir:Password>
                                    <jir:Phone>111111111</jir:Phone>
                                    <jir:SecurityAnswer>testQ</jir:SecurityAnswer>
                                    <jir:SecurityQuestion>TestAb</jir:SecurityQuestion>
                                    <jir:Username>sdf</jir:Username>
                                 </tem:user>
                              </tem:Register>
                           </soapenv:Body>
```

with use of ksoap2 library i have sucessfully created response like this:

```
          Register{user{Area=test; AvailableBalance=150; CityId=1; Email=test@test.com; FullName=Priyank; Gender=M; Mobile=9909957148; Password=testp; Phone=9909957148; SecurityAnswer=MyAns; SecurityQuestion=MyQues; Username=t; }}
```

but my problem is my values are not getting added in user tag so i am getting exception like this:

```
        Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

please give reply on this how can i parse this type of response with use of ksoap2 library.

This is my helper class which i am using for parsing resonse:

```
public class KSOAPHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "KSOAPHelper : KSOAP Helper";

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IUserService/";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "my url"             

    // Method names
    public static final String REGISTER = "Register";
    public static final String LOGIN = "Login";
    public static final String LOGOUT = "Logout";
    public static final String PROFILEDETAILS = "ProfileDetails";

    public static Object getResponce(LinkedHashMap<String, String> inputParams, String      methodName, final Context context) {

        if (Utility.isConnectionAvailable) {

            final String soap_action = SOAP_ACTION + methodName;

            Log.d(TAG, soap_action);

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodName);

            SoapObject user = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "user");

            for (String param : inputParams.keySet()) {

                Log.d(TAG, param + " : " + inputParams.get(param));
                user.addProperty(param, inputParams.get(param));
            }

            request.addSoapObject(user);            

            Log.d(TAG, "SOAP Request : " + request);
            /*
             * Set the web service envelope
             */
            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            // soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try {
                httpTransportSE.call(soap_action, soapEnvelope);
                if (soapEnvelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
                    String strFault = ((SoapFault) soapEnvelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
                    Log.v(TAG, "Fault string : " + strFault);
                } else {
                    Object object = soapEnvelope.getResponse();

                    return object;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof SocketException || e instanceof IOException) {
                    if (context instanceof Activity) {
                        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

            if (context instanceof Activity) {
                ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Internet Connection is not available");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What line is the exception occurring on? The exception is implying an object has not been initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got the solution with use of KvmSerializable class,now i am able to work on nested object also with Ksoap2 here i am sharing my code which is working fine

UserDetail Serializable class for adding user tag:

```
    public class UserDetail implements KvmSerializable {

        public String Area = null;
        public Long AvailableBalance = null;
        public Long CityId = null;
        public String Email = null;
        public String FullName = null;
        public String Gender = null;
        public String Mobile = null;
        public String Password = null;
        public String Phone = null;
        public String SecurityAnswer = null;
        public String SecurityQuestion = null;
        public String Username;
        private final String DATA_NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Jiring.MTicketing.Models";

        public UserDetail() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object getProperty(int arg0) {

            switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return this.Area;
            case 1:
                return this.AvailableBalance;
            case 2:
                return this.CityId;
            case 3:
                return this.Email;
            case 4:
                return this.FullName;
            case 5:
                return this.Gender;
            case 6:
                return this.Mobile;
            case 7:
                return this.Password;
            case 8:
                return this.Phone;
            case 9:
                return this.SecurityAnswer;
            case 10:
                return this.SecurityQuestion;
            case 11:
                return this.Username;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getPropertyCount() {
            return 12;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo arg2) {

            arg2.namespace = DATA_NAMESPACE;

            switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name = "Area";
                break;
            case 1:
                arg2.type = PropertyInfo.LONG_CLASS;
                arg2.name = "AvailableBalance";
                break;
            case 2:
                arg2.type = PropertyInfo.LONG_CLASS;
                arg2.name = "CityId";
                break;
            case 3:
                arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name = "Email";
                break;
            case 4:
                arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name = "FullName";
                break;
            case 5:
                arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name = "Gender";
                break;
            case 6:
                arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name = "Mobile";
                break;
            case 7:
                arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name = "Password";
                break;
            case 8:
                arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name = "Phone";
                break;
            case 9:
                arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name = "SecurityAnswer";
                break;
            case 10:
                arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name = "SecurityQuestion";
                break;
            case 11:
                arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                arg2.name = "Username";
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1) {

            switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                this.Area = arg1.toString();
                break;
            case 1:
                this.AvailableBalance = Long.parseLong(arg1.toString());
                break;
            case 2:
                this.CityId = Long.parseLong(arg1.toString());
                break;
            case 3:
                this.Email = arg1.toString();
                break;
            case 4:
                this.FullName = arg1.toString();
                break;
            case 5:
                this.Gender = arg1.toString();
                break;
            case 6:
                this.Mobile = arg1.toString();
                break;
            case 7:
                this.Password = arg1.toString();
                break;
            case 8:
                this.Phone = arg1.toString();
                break;
            case 9:
                this.SecurityAnswer = arg1.toString();
                break;
            case 10:
                this.SecurityQuestion = arg1.toString();
                break;
            case 11:
                this.Username = arg1.toString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

Now My Ksoap2 helper class to set http calls:

```
    public class KSOAPHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "KSOAPHelper : KSOAP Helper";

     private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IUserService/";
         private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
         private static final String URL = "my url"             


    /*
     * This method is use to getRespnce from request which return objects.
     */

    public static Object getResponce(SoapObject request, String METHOD, final Context context) {

        if (Utility.isConnectionAvailable) {

            final String soap_action = SOAP_ACTION + METHOD;

            Log.d(TAG, "SOAP Request : " + request);

            /*
             * Set the web service envelope
             */
            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelope.setAddAdornments(false);
            soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            /*
             * Calling of the web service and retrieve result.
             */

            HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try {
                // Make the soap call.
                httpTransportSE.call(soap_action, soapEnvelope);
                // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                if (soapEnvelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
                    String strFault = ((SoapFault) soapEnvelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
                    Log.d(TAG, "SOAP Request : " + httpTransportSE.requestDump);
                    Log.v(TAG, "Fault string : " + strFault);
                } else {
                    Object object = soapEnvelope.getResponse();

                    return object;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SOAP Request : " + httpTransportSE.requestDump);

                if (e instanceof SocketException || e instanceof IOException) {
                    if (context instanceof Activity) {
                        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

            if (context instanceof Activity) {
                ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    }
                });
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Internet Connection is not available");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This method can add nested object and will create request as i wanted.hope this will helpfull for some one who has same issue like me.thanks.